# variable to constant in dictionary (java openclassroom)

Tags: java

i'm learning Java by OpenClassroom but i have a problem on the dictionary.
They told me to convert variable in constant. I have to use `private static final` and the variable : `private final static months.put("June", 6);`.

Theoretically it's simple and easy but i have this : `error: illegal start of expression`.

If i try to change in `public static final` is not working..

The entire code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class MonthsMap {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> months = new HashMap <String, Integer>();   
        
        //TODO Remplacez les variables par des constantes
        months.put("June", 6);
        months.put("September", 9);
        months.put("March", 5);
          
        //TODO Corrigez "march" (mars) par sa vraie valeur (3)
     
        //TODO Supprimez "june" (juin)
     
        //Affiche le contenu du dictionnaire
        System.out.println("Here are some interesting months");
        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> month : months.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(month.getKey() + " is month number " + month.getValue() + " of the year ");
        }
    }   
}
```

I would like to know why it doesn't work, please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The only modifier you can apply to a local variable is `final`:

```java
final Map<String, Integer> months = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

If you want to make it `private static final` you'll have to convert that local variable to a member:

```java
public class MonthMap {

    private static final Map<String, Integer> months = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    static {
        months.put("June",6);
        months.put("September",9);
        months.put("March",5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /// Code goes here...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V)) method introduced in Java 9 can allow you to convert the initialization to a single statement:

```java
private static final Map<String, Integer> months =
    Map.of("June", 6, "September", 9, "March", 5);
```

Comment: I'm a begginer in Java, they told me to convert my variables : 
        
        months.put("June",6);
        months.put("September",9);
        months.put("March",5);
in constants and not to add code like an initialization
@Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know what some 3rd party website is asking for.  I suspect that they want those String and int literal values to be defined as constants.  Constants are defined on the class, not within a method.

```
public class MonthMap {
  public static final String JAN_NAME = "January";
  public static final String FEB_NAME = "February";
  ... etc ... 
  public static final int JAN_NUM = 1;
  public static final int FEB_NUM = 2;
  ... etc... 
  Map<String, Integer> months = new HashMap <String, Integer>(); 
  static {
    months.put(JAN_NAME, JAN_NUM);
    months.put(FEB_NAME, FEB_NUM);
    ... etc ...
  }
}
```